# Python Beautiful soup scrape data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am pretty new to beautifulsoup.

I have a form like this

```
<form class="addtoshoppingcart" name="addtoshoppingcart" action="/warenkorb/hinzugefuegen">
    <input name="product_id" type="hidden" value="83612">
    <input name="product_bs_id"  type="hidden" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" type="text" value="1">
    <div class="addToCartErrors"></div>
    <button id="submitAddToCart" name="addToCart" class="button radius action" disabled='disabled' autocomplete="off">
      <span>In den Warenkorb</span>
    </button>
  </form>
```

How can I safe the value, which is 83612 to a variable?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3):

It is very easy to google it. Anyways you can do it using the code below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html='''<form class="addtoshoppingcart" name="addtoshoppingcart" action="/warenkorb/hinzugefuegen">
<input name="product_id" type="hidden" value="83612">
<input name="product_bs_id"  type="hidden" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" type="text" value="1">
<div class="addToCartErrors"></div>
<button id="submitAddToCart" name="addToCart" class="button radius action" disabled='disabled' autocomplete="off">
  <span>In den Warenkorb</span>
</button>
</form>'''

soup=bs(html)

value = soup.find('input', {'name': 'product_id'}).get('value')
value = int(value) # if you want integer value
```